# C# - unable to connect to a local ACCDB file with new SqlConnection()

Tags: c#, database, connection-string

Doing a university project that requires an application that stores and outputs data from a local access DB file.

So far I have very little C# knowledge but I have a basic understanding of how to write code and what functions and methods are.

I have looked up a lot of different questions on StackOverflow and other sites about this kind of issue, yet I could not find a solution to my problem.

Here is the code -

```
private void search_db(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        string search_query = search_input.Text;
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:/Projects/WIP/8515/Academy/Travel Agency C#/Hotel_Agency/Hotel_Database.accdb;";

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE (name LIKE @query) OR (EGN LIKE @query)", conn);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("query", search_query));

        // Create new SqlDataReader object and read data from the command.
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // while there is another record present
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // write the data on to the screen
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \t | {1} \t | {2} \t | {3}",
                    // call the objects from their index
                reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on line 6 of the given code, if my ConnectionString which provides the data souce which I have triple checked and confirmed is proper, the only thing I'm not sure is what type of slash should I use, since the default \ slash from windows directories gets mistaken for an escape by Visual Studio, while with the / slash its ok.

The problem is the connection to the DB always fails with this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL

Here is the full list of the namespaces we are using for this application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

I have tried adding provider keyword to the connection string but that leads to another error about an unsupported keyword, since the System.Data.SqlClient namespace is allegedly automatically setting a provider.

Any help as to what might be causing this is appreciated!

PS: I apologize for any further lack of knowledge I present, I really am new to C# programming, but I find it quite interesting and exciting, and would like to learn more.

Comment: No, you are missing a key point here. SqlConnection and related SqlClient classes are used to work with Sql Server not with an Access Database. You need to use the System.Data.OleDbClient assembly and the OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand etc classes.

Comment: Why not use System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection instead of SqlClient ?

Comment: Ooooo so thats the issue, its not looking for a local file but a server connection, that makes sense. So I should remove the Data.SqlClient namespace and replace it with OleDbConnection one?

Comment: _using System.Data.OleDbClient;_ and then change all the SqlXXXXX with OleDbXXXXX matching classes

Comment: thanks steve, i will give it a try and if it works go ahead and place it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Also remember that in OleDb all parameters passed to a query are _positional_ so you need to supply them in the exact order in which the placeholder appears in the query. The parameters are not recognized by their name.

Comment: This link maybe help you [sql-connection-string-for-microsoft-access-2010-accdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764707/sql-connection-string-for-microsoft-access-2010-accdb)

Comment: For access database connection see connectionstrings.com : https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a common mistake here. The classes defined in the namespace *System.Data.SqlClient* (SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc.) are able to talk only with a Sql Server database system (Full, Express or LocalDb). They cannot work with an Access database.

For this database you should use the classes in the *System.Data.OleDb* namespace (OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand etc.) These classes understand the connectionstring to reach an Access database and can open and work with it.

So your code should be:

```
....
using System.Data.OleDb;

private void search_db(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ......
        conn.Open();
        string cmdText = @"SELECT * 
                           FROM Customers 
                           WHERE ([name] LIKE @q1) OR (EGN LIKE @q2)";
        using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@q1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = search_query;
            command.Parameters.Add("@q2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = search_query;
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
               ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An importat thing to remember with OleDb is that you have *positional* parameters. The parameters are not recognized by their name but by their position in the query text. So if you have two parameters placeholder, even if they are for the same value, you need to put two parameters in the collection. One for the first placeholder and one for the second placeholder. This is even more important when you have placeholders for different values. You need to add the values in the exact order in which they are expected in the query text.

Comment: OKay, I have implemented your code but I get "The the type or namespace name 'OleDbClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' on using System.Data.OleDbClient;

Comment: Sorry it is just System.Data.OleDb

Comment: Yea changed it and it works but throws "No value given for one or more required parameters" at                     using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) what kind of parameters does it need? the ones you have given seem to be proper

Comment: Sorry, but I was AFK for a couple of hours. Did you solve the latest problem?

Comment: Nah i tried numerous way of giving values to the parameters to no avail....cant really tell whats wrong at this point :/

Comment: Pay attention to the column names and table names. Anything that is not recognized as a valid system name is considered a parameter. Thus you get this message because something is not exactly what is supposed to be.

Comment: Also, [checking this list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?ocmsassetID=HA010030643&CorrelationId=761eb90b-0468-4983-a550-af7899bd75f1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#duplicate=0) you will see that _name_ is a reserved keyword for MS-Access. To use it you need square brackets around that _name_ Weird; usually this resolves in a Syntax Error Exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164498/discussion-between-denislav-karagiozov-and-steve).

Comment: `NotImplementedException: OleDb is not implemented.`

Comment: NotImplementedException has nothing to do with this code. I suggest you to post a new question with many details about your problem.